# C++ using fstream to find a specific data

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm new to C++ and need help with fstream.  I've searched and read and can't find this information.

I want to get a data from a specific line in a txt file.

For example in a txt file, I have :

10 rows and 11 columns, each column is either int, char, string, etc.

Is there anyway I can retrieve one variable from a specific row and column, without using array?

Ex: if I want to retrieve the variable from row 9 and column 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Skip 8 "rolls" and then skip 3 columns and then read one thing?

Comment: What you're asking is at it's core: `how do I jump to a particular spot in file?` You can't anything that anyone suggests, such as what immibis and the already provided answer suggest, is to read through the file until you're at the part that you want, then record the part you want, then close the file. You can't just jump to a spot in a file without knowing where it is.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly how long every line and and where each column is in each row you can compute exactly where you want to go and [use `seekg`to position yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

With the data stored as text this is uncommon. You usually have to write a function that does the following:

1. Open the file
2. Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on the file N times to get to the Nth row from the file.
3. Write the row into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).
4. Use  `>>` on the `std::stringstream` M times to read columns into a  `std::string`.
5. Convert Mth column from `std::string` to the appropriate data type.
6. return converted Mth column.

Answer (score 0):

```
//-------------------------------
//--This code maybe can help you
//-------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main ()
{

    char lBuffer[100];
    //---
    std::string myfilename = "/var/log/mylog.log";
    std::ifstream log_file ( myfilename );
    std::stringstream my_ss;
    std::string c1, c2, c3;
    //---
    std::cout << "Rec1\t\t Rec2\t\t Rec3" << std::endl;
    while ( ! log_file.eof() )
    {
            log_file.getline(lBuffer,80);
            my_ss << lBuffer;

            my_ss >> c1;
            my_ss >> c2;
            my_ss >> c3;

            std::cout << c1 << "\t\t " << c2 << "\t\t "   << c3 << std::endl;

    }

}
//---
```